# How to update a PowerPoint slide while presenting

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I need to find a way to update a powerpoint slide mid-presentation with images based on audience feedback (ie. audience votes for an image and then that image gets put on a slide later).

I'm concerned about the risk of editing in presentation mode and the editor inadvertently exiting the slideshow in the middle of the presentation.

Are there any add-ons etc. that can be used in PowerPoint to edit/modify a slide during mid presentation while preventing the risk of messing up the live presentation if possible?

Ideas thus far:

- Using the LiveWeb plugin and an FTP site/Dropbox to point to an image and overwrite the image on the LiveWeb slide based on audience feedback (too complicated for the editors that will be doing this live)
- Update presentation remotely while on a shared network (not sure if PPT will update this live.).
- **Update:** As long as the presentation is using "Presenter View" and an extended monitor, you can navigate through the entire computer and edit any slide on the PowerPoint. Edited slides will show the updated content/images in the live presentation. Doing this, however, pauses the live presentation. So if the person presenting needs to go to the next slide or activate an animation while you are editing, it won't happen until the presentation is resumed. This seems like it will work as long as the presenter doesn't try to move to the next slide before the editor is done editing. Any add-ins that allow for simultaneos editing AND navigation of the presentation?

Has anyone ever done something like this before? What did you do to make it work in a live presentation?

Comment: Good luck. Even if there was some magic software that could do this, you'd have the problem where you'd basically be trying to work in a file that's already open. Unless somehow you could get it to link to some other file, I dunno. Somebody prove me wrong?

Answer (score 4):

In PowerPoint 2013, it is really very simple:

1. In Presenter View, click on Show Taskbar (upper left corner)
2. When taskbar opens at bottom of screen, click on PowerPoint tab,
3. In three views that are shown (Editor, Presenter and SlideShow), click on the Editor view.
4. If you want audience to see your changes as you make them, have same slide showing in all 3 views.
5. If you don't want audience to see changes until you are done, click the Black screen icon in Presenter View (Monitor with diagonal line across), before you start your change, OR change to a different slide in Presenter view.
6. Slideshow will show your changed slide on the big screen, when you go to it.

Happy PowerPointing!

Comment: The question is about ver 2010.  Do you know whether this will work in that version?

Comment: Yes it will work

Answer (score 2):

This is really quite simple, especially since you say you want to change a slide that's not currently in view (which can get tricky due to bugs in some PPT versions).

Add this to a VBA module in your presentation.
You'll have to save the presentation as PPTM or PPSM rather than PPTX/PPTX.

Follow the instrux included as comments:

```vb
Option Explicit

' We'll modify slide #4 ... change as needed
' Make sure that the slide has no empty content or picture placeholders on it
Const lSlideNum As Long = 4

Sub AddAnImage()
    ' add a shape to any slide you like
    ' assign the shape an Action Setting of Run Macro: AddAnImage

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(lSlideNum)

    ' bring in the image; setting width/height to -1 ensures that you
    ' don't distort it
    Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddPicture("c:\temp\photo.jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, -1, -1)

    With oSh
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue ' to make sure it stays undistorted
        ' change its position/size as you wish
        ' for example, let's make it the full width of the slide:
        .Width = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot. So essentially, this code would use a shape as a placeholder and look for an image in a file directory, correct?

Comment: In this case, it just adds the picture directly, no placeholder as such.  It wouldn't be hard to extend it a bit to name the picture once it's inserted, then before adding a new picture, delete the old.  I'll pop a little aircode for that into a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

MDT is closer than he might think; I used to brief a stack of presentations some of which were being edited during the show.  The key is to create the master presentation as a smooth interface to a collection of presentations.  I used to get this done in Office 97; I'm sure it can be done now.
If that suits your needs, static link to a volatile presentation (but with a stable filename) might be the thing.

Comment: How did you go about editing the other slides(presentations) while giving the presentation? Was someone in the room updating files on a shared network drive?

Comment: @Ian, Yes, that's exactly it.  For extra smoothness, I would open all of the child presentations first, then open the one that linked to them.  That was not necessary however, it just avoided some wait time for opening things when the link was clicked.  If you can accept that slight wait, then you can have somebody roll emergent changes into a separate linked presentation while the meeting is in session.
Caution -- the other file MUST be closed and saved by the other user by the time you want to use it.
Also, I believe SharePoint has some awesome magic for this sort of thing. But I don't know.

Comment: It canbe done in Office 2013 by the way...

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

' We'll modify slide #4 ... change as needed ' Make sure that the slide has no empty content or picture placeholders on it Const lSlideNum As Long = 4

Sub AddAnImage()
    ' add a shape to any slide you like
    ' assign the shape an Action Setting of Run Macro: AddAnImage

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(lSlideNum)

    ' NEW:  Delete any existing image we may have added previously
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oSh = oSl.Shapes("MagicImage")
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
       oSh.Delete
    End If

    ' bring in the image; setting width/height to -1 ensures that you
    ' don't distort it
    Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddPicture("c:\temp\photo.jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, -1, -1)

    With oSh
        ' NEW:  Name it so we can locate it easily later:
        .Name = "MagicImage"
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue ' to make sure it stays undistorted
        ' change its position/size as you wish
        ' for example, let's make it the full width of the slide:
        .Width = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever thought about custom shows?  Create a single PPT file with all the different combinations possible.  As you click through the slides and select a picture hyperlink to a custom show that includes the correct picture.  With a little thought and a tree to track all possible combinations, you can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, but as someone who needed to be able to update future slides without interrupting the current show, I found that Powershow worked exactly how I needed it to work. The changes in 2013 are great, however, it does not allow the user to edit the show without affecting what the audience sees.

The dance school I work for uses slides and sometimes movies during our recital. There were a few times where I clicked a different slide and cut off the sound for the video displaying because it cut off the show. I did some research and found Powershow. It took a little getting used to, but is exactly what I needed.

I can do whatever I want, including update and rearrange, as well as delete upcoming slides, while the show displays in a different session in powerpoint.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SU! You could include a link to the above mentioned software in your answer.